# Socket.io backward compatibility of server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to update my socket.io version on both client and server (browser + Node.js). I have to manage legacy clients using older versions of the library. How can I be sure that v2.x of socket.io server is compatible with, let's say, v1.7.2 on socket.io client?

Comment: You could have the newest socket.io version on a different port? And point the newest clients to that port instead of the other. Then again, the client side of the api should not have too many issues with the server side, as it should still follow the same WebSocket principles

Comment: v2 isn't backward compatible with v1, as stated [in this blog post](https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-2-0-0/). I'm not sure if you can use two SocketIO servers in the same HTTP server, but if not, @tgdn's idea of having the new one listen on a different port (can still be the same application) is probably the best solution. Do the legacy clients have the client code "baked in"? Typically, the SocketIO client code is retrieved dynamically (using `<script...>`)

Comment: @robertklep, legacy clients are mobile apps: socket.io client code is bundled.

Comment: Another issue that I just realized is that you (obviously) can't install both `socket.io@1` and `socket.io@2` in the same project directory, so you can't use them in the same project/app.

Comment: You're right. That's why I think that next refactor will segregate socket.io in a separate process and implement IPC. This way, different socket.io versions will talk with the same application server